# CiviCRM Stripe PCI Compliance

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, payment-processor, stripe

I am using the latest version of the Stripe extension (5.2) and have CiviCRM up-to-date and Drupal. I'm getting this error in my Stripe portal, I only use Stripe with CiviCRM. Can anyone provide some insight? Was not sure if i should post this here or at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues

[image]

Comment: Has Stripe changed its policy recently? [Previously it stated](http://web.archive.org/web/20170120013605/https://stripe.com/docs/security) that "As long as you serve your payment pages over TLS, and use either Checkout or Stripe.js as the only way of handling card information, Stripe automatically creates a prefilled SAQ A questionnaire for you, and you won’t need to undergo a PCI audit". But now that page states for Stripe.js v2 (which the extension uses) it states "Requirement: SAQ A-EP" (unless using Elements with Stripe.js).

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_stripe/issues/2959726

Comment: You say "I am using the latest version of the Stripe extension (5.2)" but the latest Release is 6.3.2 - can you clarify in your Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripe development team has upgraded the code of the extension to support the new API that is PCI compliant.